# c++ persisting data

Tags: c++, templates

what I want to archive is a simple way to make some variables persistent. 
For this I wrote a PeristenceProvider Class which wraps the boost property tree functionality
to store data in xml / ini files.

At the moment I need to do things like this:

```
ClassA::ClassA()
{
   m_valueI = PersistenceProvider::getInstance.get<int>("valueI");
}

ClassA::~ClassA()
{
    PeristenceProvider::getInstance.set<int>("valueI", m_valueI);
}
```

But is there a chance to hide this in a way like this:

```
class ClassA
{
     Persist<int, "valueI"> m_ValueI;
}
```

Comment: I think you can get close with templates, but for you'll need macro magic to make it exactly like that.

Comment: If you need to generate string identifiers from variable names you will need macros

Comment: Can you pass the string literal as a template parameter?

Comment: I wouldn't mind to add a second template parameter containing the name

Comment: Passing strings a template parameter is not allowed! You can use ordinal numbers though. Besides this i wouldnt make the variable constantly persistent but would store it at exact spots or use a Marshaller/Unmarshaller architecture. The Configuration framework from Poco is quite nice to do such things: http://pocoproject.org/slides/180-Configuration.pdf

Comment: @Paranaix This is not true in C++11 where meta-programming with strings actually becomes useful. See http://abel.web.elte.hu/mpllibs/metaparse/index.html

Comment: It is very interesting to write one's own persistence lib. But it's also very difficult. You should look at how other persistence libraries are working. I know of this one : Wt::Dbo http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/dbo.html

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but not exactly that way. You cannot use string literals to instantiate template. String objects with external linkage are only allowed to be non-type arguments.
So string constant must be defined as `extern` and be `char[]`, not just `char*`.

See example (it will print "Hello" and "World", really cool, isn't it?):

```
extern const char hello[] = "Hello";
extern const char world[] = "World";

template<const char* s> struct X
{
   X()
   {
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
   }
};

X<hello> z1;
X<world> z2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not persisting tons of info - just a few choice parameters.  If so, then just wrap the function calls in your own functions that take two arguments -  a std::string or const char * and the type of the item being persisted.  If the number of types being persisted is limited (e.g. int, double, std::string), this will work fine.